# Display List of All Taxomony Terms of A Post

Tags: taxonomy

I have created a Taxonomy named “Genre”.

In one of my posts, I added the following categories to its “Genre”

- Funny
- Action
- Adventure

How can I display Funny, Action, and Adventure under the title of my post, like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLRtI.png

Or is there a way to display this in my article via shortcode?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use the template tag [`the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy, $before = '', $sep = ', ', $after = '' )`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/)

For example:

```php
<?php the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'genre', 'Genres: ', ' ' ) ?>
```